# Are there any alternative for getSystemSelection()?

Tags: java, clipboard

I am trying to get data from the clipboard using `getSystemSelection()` but it's returning `null`. Most references say that some platforms don't support this. Is there any alternative?

Here is my current code:

```
Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection();
System.out.println(c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString());
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This question is not very clear.

Comment: Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection(); System.out.println(c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString()); this is is what am trying.

Comment: I added the code to your question. I'm still not sure if it is enough information. Could you post a minimal working (as in compiling and returning the null) code?

Comment: Plus, could you post the references you are mentioning in the question?

Comment: @Burkhard The question looks adequate to me. I don't think there's any fixing `getSystemSelection` that returns `null`, an alternative is required (so a minimal test case won't / shouldn't help much, and is likely to be platform-dependent, so won't really be reproducable). [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemSelection()) is one such reference.

Comment: @amarnath Could you specify your environment? (Java version, OS version,...) If your environment is currently not supported there is probably no platform independent java-only solution for your problem.